# Log4net configuring programmatically an adoAppender

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I need to add an ado appender to an existing log4net config.

I need to add it via code. However i'm stuck on adding common string parameters like message as I can't define the layout property correctly : In xml configuration, we use PatternLayout, but via code PatternLayout is not a IRowLayout so I have an error with the following code :

```
    public static void AddStringParameterToAppender(this log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender appender, string paramName, int size, string conversionPattern)
    {
        log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter param = new log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter();
        param.ParameterName = paramName;
        param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
        param.Size = size;
        param.Layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout(conversionPattern);
        appender.AddParameter(param);
    }
```

Does someone know how to add a string parameter in code which is similar to the following xml sample :

```
<parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've finally found how to transform the `PatternLayout` in an `IRawLayout`.

To do this, you have to use `log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter`:

```
public static void AddStringParameterToAppender(this log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender appender, string paramName, int size, string conversionPattern)
    {
        log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter param = new log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter();
        param.ParameterName = paramName;
        param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.String;
        param.Size = size;
        param.Layout = new log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter(new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout(conversionPattern));
        appender.AddParameter(param);
    }
```

Comment: Small typo, it should be "Layout2RawLayoutAdapter" (not *Row*).